How to do sparse-checkout in a buildConfig using OpenShift?
I have a mono-repo containing multiple projects.
I would like to prevent my build from having to download multiple MB just to throw them away, since Im only interested of building a single project. From my understanding this could be achieved using git sparse-checkout, and Im currently using that in a combination with binary build. However, this has lead me down a path thats not very convenient. I figured that I cant be the first with a mono-repo running OpenShift and want to either control the "flow" of how git is executed during the build.. or if there is some attribute to set to the buildConfig to limit which files are downloaded from the repository. Any ideas?
